# Clock isn't starting

Tags: java

I wrote a little Clock in JavaFX8. On my GUI, I have 2 Buttons. One button should start the timer and the other button should pause the timer. But whenever I press start, nothing is happening. When I delete the whole `if()` clause, I am able to start the timer via `thread.start` and it's updating my GUI. I think my call `if(isRunning)` isn't working how I want.
I appreciate any kind of help!

My Window.java (Main Application)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gui;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import logic.Clock;
import logic.ClockObserver;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Window extends Application implements Observer {

    private Button b_start = new Button("Start");
    private Button b_stop = new Button("Stop");
    private Label l_time = new Label("gdfgdf");
    private HBox buttonbox = new HBox();
    private Clock clock = new Clock();
    private Thread thread = new Thread(clock);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        thread.start();
        buttonbox.setSpacing(5.0);
        clock.addObserver(this);
        buttonbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttonbox.getChildren().addAll(b_start, b_stop);
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setPadding(new Insets(10.0));
        bp.setCenter(l_time);
        bp.setBottom(buttonbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(150);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Uhr");
        primaryStage.show();
        
        b_start.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->{
            clock.setRunning(true);
        });
        
        b_stop.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->{
            clock.setRunning(false);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                l_time.setText(clock.getZeit());
            }
            
        });
    }
    

}
```

My Clock.java

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package logic;

import gui.Window;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Clock extends Observable implements Runnable {

    private String zeit = "";
    private int sek;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public Clock() {

    }

    public void setZeit() {
        zeit = "" + sek;
    }

    public String getZeit() {
        return zeit;
    }
    
    public void setRunning(boolean running){
        this.isRunning = running;
    }
    
    public boolean isRunning(){
        return isRunning;
    }

    public int getSek() {
        return sek;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (isRunning()) {
                try {
                    sek++;
                    setZeit();
                    System.out.println(zeit);
                    this.setChanged();
                    this.notifyObservers();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    //TODO
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to make methods `isRunning` and `setRunning` synchronized ?

Comment: also have you looked into something built in the jdk ? I don't know your requirements but javafx has `TimeLine` and `AnimationTimer`, java also have `java.util.Timer`

Comment: Making the methonds synchronized is working. Can you explain me, why its the case? And yes, i looked for something built in the jdk, but i wanted to create something new for training my skills. :)

Comment: I don't know at all, yes `running` is a shared resource between the two but loss of synchronization would make the clock thread read the old value of `running`, the impact of this is insignificant and it shouldn't result in that

Comment: Also I make my program launch in "Debug" mode without setting any breakpoints, I press start button and nothing happens, I set a breakpoint on `if(isRunning()`, it hits, I remove it and make my program continue, it works !!!!! and the stop button works too !!!!!

Comment: side advice : `thread.setDaemon(true)` is reasonable , otherwise when you close the window the thread will still be running

Comment: I cant understand why i have to make the methods synchronized. First of all, directly after i start the Thread, the Clock stucks in a while-loop because theres no ending condition. That means, that there normally has to be a call every millisec(?) if the boolean has been changed or not. So why do i need to add synchronized to the methods? Can somebody help me to understand?

Comment: Yes, i know. I directly added a setOnCloseRequest Event after my post. Sorry for not updating

Comment: And when i am following your steps, it still wont work for me. Dont know why.. Its only working when i make the methods synchronized

Comment: note that making `isRunning` synchronized was enough for me, `setRunning` didn't need to

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for noticing that. But i still cant understand, why i need to do it synchronized :D